# Running different python version

Tags: python-2.7, python-2.5

I happen to have a problem in executing different versions of python. I have python 2.7 and 2.5 installed. If i want to run a script using 2.5 version i just include `#!python2.5` and it works.
Now my problem is that my whole application is using 2.7. Using PIL library in 2.7 version doesn't generate the proper results and so i am using python version 2.5 to generate images using font.

My main file contains:

```
import func
if __name__=='__main__':
    i=func.gen("Hey there")
    i.save("img.png")
```

This calls the function written in the script func.py

```
#!python2.5
import Image,ImageDraw,ImageFont
def gen(txt):
    im=Image.new('RGBA',(200,200))
    font=ImageFont.truetype("abc.ttf",100)
    draw  =  ImageDraw.Draw (im)
    draw.text ( ( 0 , 0), txt, font=font, fill="#FFFFFF" )
    return im
```

This script runs with python2.5 version when i execute it separately.
but when i call this in main file, it runs with 2.7 version. Can anybody provide a solution?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Do you want to use python 2.5 for the whole application? Or python 2.7? Or some kind of Frankenstein-like combination of both?

Comment: I want to use 2.7 for the whole application but there is a script or two where i need to use 2.5 version. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to execute a part of your application with another python version is to call it externally.

This can be achieved by using `subprocess` or similar methods. As long as you call the methods from the second script when the first one is started with `python2.7` they will get executed by `python2.7`.

A second solution would be to implement an "image rendering daemon" which is running with `python2.5` and gets called through socket / HTTP by your `python2.7` application.

Comment: can u provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

I did it. I used Popen from subprocess.

```
p=Popen(['cmd', '/C', 'py -2.5 func.py'], stdout = PIPE)
pp= p.communicate()[0]
```